# printer config uses wrong language

Tags: drivers, printing

I speak English, all of my menus and such in Ubuntu are in English.  I have a repeated problem during the past few years and I wonder if anybody else sees it too.

The CUPS printer system regularly installs a printer ppd file that has Simplified Chinese as the language.  Because of that, programs that want to print do not display menu items correctly, presumably because the menu items are in Chinese.

Years ago, I tracked the problem down to a ppd file that comes in with the printer configurator.  Here's the top of the ppd file:

```
*PPD-Adobe: "4.3"
*% Linux Version
*%
*% This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
*% under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free
*% Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or (at your option)
*% any later version.
*%
*% This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT
*% ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or
*% FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU General Public License for
*% more details.
*%
*% You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License along with
*% this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple
*% Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA

*FormatVersion: "4.3"
*LanguageVersion: Simplified Chinese
*LanguageEncoding: None
*FileVersion: "20002.0000"

*Manufacturer: "KONICA MINOLTA"
*ModelName: "KONICA MINOLTA C451 PS/P"
*ShortNickName: "KONICA MINOLTA C451 PS(P)"
*NickName: "KONICA MINOLTA C451 PS(P)"
*PCFileName: "KOC451SCX.ppd"
*Product: "(C451)"
*PSVersion: "(3015.102) 1"
```

I've gone through the same experience several times over the past few years.   I get the correct ppd file from Konica Minolta, install it with the printer configurator.  That puts the "right" file in /etc/cups/ppd, it has the name "KM.ppd" because KM is the name I give to that printer. After an Ubuntu version upgrade, the KM.ppd file I insert gets replaced by the Simplified Chinese one. So I put the right one in place of the one that the printer configurator installs there. All is well, the menus work in apps that want to print.

And then an Ubuntu system update comes along and replaces the ppd file with one that assumes I want Simplified Chinese. The first time this happened, it was difficult to figure out.  The second time, I knew I'd fixed it before but could not remember how.  Now I'm on the 6th or 7th time and it is on the list of things.

This time I've decided to take away write permission on KM.ppd, we'll see if Ubuntu leaves it alone.

Mostly I wonder why other people aren't complaining about this kind of thing.  Maybe it is only a Konica-Minolta driver issue?

Comment: can I suggest you report this as a bug to the Ubuntu team; they are very good at chasing stuff up ...... bugs .. launchpad.net ..... ubuntu

Comment: It just happened again in the Ubuntu 19.04 update, so I created a bug report:https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/1829274